# Double data-confirm prompt observed on rails with framework7

Tags: ruby-on-rails, html-framework-7

When you use `data-confirm` on framework7 embedded in rails, a double prompt is observed. The first prompt is coming from Rails. The other is coming from framework7.

```
<div class="swipeout-actions-right">
  <a id="more_button" href="#" data-task-id={{id}} class="demo-actions">
      <span class="small">More</span>
    </a>
  <a id="archive_button" href="#" data-task-id={{id}} class="bg-blue demo-actions">
      <span class="small">Archive</span></a>
  <a href="#" class="bg-green swipeout-delete swipeout-overswipe" data-confirm="Are you sure want to delete this item?">
    <span class="small">Complete</span>
  </a></div>
```

Does anyone has a recommended solution to the double prompt of `data-confirm` this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update**: I fix it by disabling `rails.confirm`

```
$.rails.confirm = function(){return true}
```

You can also fix the issue by removing `//= require jquery_ujs`.