# Duplicate method-delete on rails using axios

Tags: ruby-on-rails, axios

Due to a [previous issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45433422/double-data-confirm-prompt-observed-on-rails-with-framework7/45433423#45433423), I have to remove `//= require jquery_ujs` from application.js

Now, I need to replace the `/users/sign_out` method with an ajax using axios. The following is my code:

```
axios.delete("users/sign_out", { 
  headers: { 
    "X-CSRF-Token": $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content') },
  params: { 
    "authenticity_token": $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
  }
})
.then(function(response) {
    alert(response)
})
.catch(function(error) {
    alert(error)
})
```

The server log shows that there is a DELETE "/" right after the delete "/users/sign_out". This is not correct.

```
Started DELETE "/users/sign_out?authenticity_token=mHQ3d4lJzDNS5TSWEFkDZ%2F3fI0vTDFxW6CabEffaNk6h2JRYNk8kkgCSBOXFdHmgDKcVtY8e29aGU%2F3q9gajWA%3D%3D" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-08-01 20:59:55 +0800
Processing by Devise::SessionsController#destroy as HTML
  Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"mHQ3d4lJzDNS5TSWEFkDZ/3fI0vTDFxW6CabEffaNk6h2JRYNk8kkgCSBOXFdHmgDKcVtY8e29aGU/3q9gajWA=="}
  User Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT $2  [["id", 2], ["LIMIT", 1]]
   (0.2ms)  BEGIN
   (0.2ms)  COMMIT
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/
Completed 302 Found in 8ms (ActiveRecord: 0.9ms)


**Started DELETE "/" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-08-01 20:59:55 +0800**

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [DELETE] "/"):
```

Comment: Can you add your routes and your Devise::SessionsController?

Comment: Did my answer solve your problem? If so, could you please mark it as accepted?  Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**TL;DR - set `config.sign_out_via = :get` in initializers/devise.rb**

Devise is [responding from the server with a `redirect_to`](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/app/controllers/devise/sessions_controller.rb#L78) when `DELETE /users/sign_out` is requested.  The default HTTP status code used by rails for `redirect_to` is `302 Found`. The `302` status was originally meant to indicate that the browser should retry the same request with the *same* method, but this was subverted early on by many browsers which were changing the request method to `GET` automatically (see the [RFC 1945 Note regarding `302 Moved Temporarily`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1945#section-9.3))

The [Rails docs for `redirect_to`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Redirecting.html#method-i-redirect_to) also have a note about this specifically as it relates to non-standard HTTP request methods via AJAX:

> If you are using XHR requests other than GET or POST and redirecting after the request then some browsers will follow the redirect using the original request method. This may lead to undesirable behavior such as a double DELETE.

The solution is to return a `303 See Other` like this: `redirect_to resource_path, status: 303`. I have looked for a way to set the HTTP status for the `Devise::SessionsController#destroy` and it doesn't seem to exist at this time in the Devise API.

However, you can tell Devise to use GET as the request method for sign out in the Devise initializer:

```
# in initializers/devise.rb
Devise.setup do |config|
  . . .
  config.sign_out_via = :get
  . . . 
end
```

Now when you visit the sign out link you should see `GET /users/sign_out` in your server logs and the browser redirect should also use GET.

Some other resources I used to research this issue:

- [This Stack Overflow response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20978913/3938081) gave me the first big clue
- [HTTP/1.1 RFC 7231](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.4.3)
- [W3 HTTP status code docs](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.3.3)

Answer (score 0):

You can also solve this by ensuring the `axios` request has an `Accept` header with `'application/json'`. As it can be seen in the [devise source code](https://github.com/heartcombo/devise/blob/v4.7.3/app/controllers/devise/sessions_controller.rb#L75) for the sessions controller:

```
  def respond_to_on_destroy
    # We actually need to hardcode this as Rails default responder doesn't
    # support returning empty response on GET request
    respond_to do |format|
      format.all { head :no_content }
      format.any(*navigational_formats) { redirect_to after_sign_out_path_for(resource_name) }
    end
  end
```

Which means it should respond with `head :no_content` for any non-navigational format, avoiding the redirect.